# C program linked list add to end

Tags: c, linked-list, append

This program is supposed to take an item from the user and put it at the end of the list.

If I enter: `batteries, flashlight and pens as the item name.`

The order should be

```
 1 batteries
 2 flashlight
 3 pens
```

However the order is:

```
 3 pens
 2 flashlight
 1 batteries
```

My Code is:

```
struct item *end_of_list(struct item *inventory)
{
    struct item *cur, *new_node;

    new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct item));

    if (new_node == NULL) { 
        printf("malloc failed\n");
        return inventory;
    }

    printf("Enter item ID: \n");
    scanf("%d", &new_node->number);

    for(cur=inventory; cur != NULL; cur = cur->next) {
        if (cur != NULL && new_node->number == cur->number) {
            printf("item already exists: %s\n",new_node->item_name);
            free(new_node);
            return inventory;
        }
    }

    printf("Enter item name: \n");
    printf("%s, new_node->item_name")

    new_node->next = NULL;

    if (inventory == NULL) {
        inventory = new_node->next;
    } else {
        while (new_node->next != NULL) {
            new_node = new_node->next;
        }   
        new_node->next = inventory;
    }
    return new_node;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you reversed `inventory` and `new_node` at the bottom of your function.  Your assignment in the `NULL` case is also wrong, since `new_node->next` is `NULL`.  Try the following:

```
if (inventory == NULL) {
    inventory = new_node;
} else {
    cur = inventory;
    while (cur->next != NULL) {
        cur = cur->next;
    }
    cur->next = new_node;
}
return inventory;
```